# How to solve this Area problem using integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

[image]

[image]

My working:
Find length $AB$ and calculate area. Integrate $f(x)$ at $B$ and $C$. Integrate $g(x)$ at $A$ and$D$. $A1 + A2 - Area red = Paved Area$.

But this seems very tedious and a lot of work, I am sure that is a shorter way of doing this but I just could not see it? Could it be integral $f(x) - g(x)$ ? but this doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

Comment: You have two areas, just explicitly make each one upper minus lower function, but it's the same amount of integration work as what you propose.

Comment: Consider finding area between the blue graph and $y$-axis above $AB$ using $\int\limits_{y_A}^{f(0)} f^{-1}(y)\,dy$ and subtractiing this value from $\int\limits_0^{x_D} f(x)-g(x)\, dx$